# Retrieving a part of information from a string output

Tags: python-3.x, string

To just give you an overview: I have used a library called paramiko to connect to a storage server through SSH to access various details and one of them being the hardware status of the server. I have successfully pulled the data as output and I am facing difficulty to parse through it to retrieve the power status. The data pulled is in a string format and I only need a particular line. Would really appreciate it if you could help me.

If you take a look at the output, The particular line I want to retrieve is:

> [PS0]: Present, AC Good, DC Good

Note: The output you see below is all in string format.

```
***********************************
Main Chassis status
***********************************
Controller ID:                 0
Second controller installed:   1
Second controller presence:    1
Power Supply information:
   [PS0]: Present, AC Good, DC Good
   [PS0]: +12V Voltage     = 12.34 Volts (Normal)
   [PS0]: +12V Current     = 9.56 Amps
   [PS0]: +12V Power       = 116.75 Watts
   [PS0]: +5V Voltage      = 5.13 Volts (Normal)
   [PS0]: Temp Sensor1     = 30 C (Normal)
   [PS0]: Temp Sensor2     = 29 C (Normal)
   [PS0]: Fan1 Speed       = 4688 RPM (Normal)
   [PS0]: Fan2 Speed       = 4688 RPM (Normal)
   [PS1]: Present, AC Good, DC Good
   [PS1]: +12V Voltage     = 12.34 Volts (Normal)
   [PS1]: +12V Current     = 9.56 Amps
   [PS1]: +12V Power       = 116.75 Watts
   [PS1]: +5V Voltage      = 5.13 Volts (Normal)
   [PS1]: Temp Sensor1     = 29 C (Normal)
   [PS1]: Temp Sensor2     = 30 C (Normal)
   [PS1]: Fan1 Speed       = 4688 RPM (Normal)
   [PS1]: Fan2 Speed       = 4688 RPM (Normal)
Temperature readings: (in degree C)
   [T1 - Front temperature]:    34 (Normal)
   [T2 - Rear temperature]:     33 (Normal)
   [T3 - CPU temperature]:      33 (Normal)
   [T4 - Midplane temperature]: 29 (Normal)
   [T5 - Midplane temperature]: 29 (Normal)
Voltage readings: (in volt)
   [V1]: 1.54 (Normal)
   [V2]: 3.34 (Normal)
   [V3]: 5.13 (Normal)
   [V4]: 12.34 (Normal)
   [V5]: 0.86 (Normal)
   [V6]: 1.06 (Normal)
   [V7]: 3.17 (Normal)
Battery Information:
   Remaining capacity percentage: 92 %
   Estimated backup time:         89.1 Hours
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Regex (Regular expression) to search for that particular format and use it. Python has [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) as `re` module.

Let the hardware status string mentioned above be `hardware_status`.

So the code to search the pattern is as follows:

```
import re

ind_hardware_status = hardware_status.split('\n')
for status in ind_hardware_status:
    match = re.search("\s*\[PS0\]: .* AC .* DC .*$", status) # Search Pattern
    if match:
        print(match.group(0).strip())
```

This code assumes that **AC, DC** will be present in that line.